# Issue installing react-native-firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm attempting to install react-native-firebase on an iOS project.
I've followed all instructions but keep having issue

I get the following error:

[image]

However, I'm able to import `<Firebase.h>` from the `AppDelegate.m` file

I've tried different way to troubleshoot:

- `pod update`
- Uncommented `platform :ios, '9.0'`
- Cleaned project
- Reinstalled everything
- Added Header Search Paths in Build Settings with: `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase` in recursive

[image]

[image]

... I'm not sure what is left to try!

This is the dependencies downloaded by Pod:

```
Using Firebase (5.1.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.1)
Using FirebaseCore (5.0.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.0.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
```

Any idea what else could cause this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `"$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Firebase"` to your header search paths?

Comment: Yep I did try this too :(

Answer (score 4):

1. Update react-native-firebase with latest version run : react-native-firebase@latest with yarn or npm.
2. In your pod file make sure you have this exact same line :

   `pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase.podspec'`
3. cd ios and run pod update RNFirebase.
4. If the above steps don't solve the issue. Try replacing :pod 'Firebase/Core', '~>
   4.13.0'

Follow [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1061) link if it still exists

Answer (score 1):

Try with this pod.

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with only pod

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

and manually link RNFirebase in IOS. This should work.

Comment: Only Firebase without RNfirebase works. But adding RNfirebase to the project breaks

Comment: Did you remove other pods Firebase, FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseInstanceID, GoogleToolboxForMac and manually link react-native-firebase?